# Rails 3 - Form Validation - Moving Logic to an Callback or Observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Hey all, I'm having issues with validation that I've been working on the last couple of days with no luck. What I have is that I have a model that requires the user to input a URL. I've done this with the following in my model:

```
validates :url, :presence => true
```

When a user submits their form, I take their URL and open it with Nokogiri to pull basic things like the webpage title. I'm currently doing this with my Create method in the controller. Code looks like so:

```
def create
    require 'open-uri'
    @page = Page.new(params[:page])

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@page.url))
```

The problem I run in to, is that if the user enters a blank form, Nokogiri will error out as it runs even though I've tried to validate the form.

My question is, should I be moving this sort of logic to a callback or an observer? I'm pretty new to rails but would there be a way for me to work with my data/instance variables from a callback/observer? I've failed simply using @page, but was wondering if there was a way I'm supposed to pass it into the callback/observer if this is where this sort of logic is supposed to be placed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be better to put this in the model.

Controller method does something like

```
def create
  @page = Page.new(params[:page])
  respond_with @page
end
```

and in the model you have

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_save :pull_info_from_url

  def pull_info_from_url
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(self.url))
    ...
  end
end
```

the `before_save` callback is run after validations, so if the presence-check fails, this code doesn't get executed, and the form with errors is shown instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. It's now working like a charm. I had another question about callbacks that I couldn't find while reading over some documentation. Is there a way to run this before_save callback only after the create method? As it stands it is running after update as well before it saves. I need to segregate it so it's only after the create, thus why I originally had the logic in that method on the controller.

Comment: In the start of pull_info_from_url, you could say "return unless new_record?" which I believe would accomplish this. Or you could use before_create instead of before_save. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks has more information on callbacks and validations.